# Weird mouse behaviour on M1 MacBook Air with RealVNC Viewer on external monitor

Tags: macos, remote-desktop, apple-silicon

One of my guys has an 2020 MacBook Air M1 (Apple silicon). This is connected via USB-C to an external monitor, a Dell U2720Q.

On this laptop we're running the latest (7.8) version of RealVNC Viewer for macOS. I believe this is an x86 program. We're using this to connect to a Rocky Linux 8.8 server running a VNC server, to use the Linux graphical desktop on the Mac.

A couple of months ago, we started to observe some very weird behaviour. When "in" VNC, on the external monitor, some mouse clicks "don't come through", others do but they resize other windows.

We've tried several different mice as well as the trackpad, same issue.

We've tried a completely different VNC server/machine, same issue.

We've tried three different external monitors, same issue.

But if we detach the external monitor and just use the built in laptop display, everything is fine.

The very same VNC session, when accessed from a different laptop, works fine.

This is the only M1 MacBook Air in our small office, so it could be Apple Silicon related. We haven't been able to reproduce the problem on an Intel MacBook.